# Поиск по сериализованному массиву в базе данных

Tags: php, mysql

У меня у каждой записи есть теги. Мне советовали запихнуть их сериализованный массив. Я так и сделал) Теперь возникла необходмость вывести все записи с определенным тегом. Как это будет выглядеть в `PHP` и какой запрос делать `MySQL`?

Comment: У меня сложилось такое впечатление, что Вам неправильно посоветовали, так как сейчас нужно вынимать все записи, десериализировать их в цикле и по ходу выдергивать с нужным тегом.

Если теги так важны, то их нужно сохранять в отдельных ячейках и делать по ним выборку.

Comment: @inferus-vv, а вы бы задали этот вопрос тому "умнику", который вам посоветовал такой вариант решения задачи. Тэги вынесите в отдельную таблицу. Еще одна таблица, где будут храниться связки: **id тэга** => **id статьи**

Comment: Вот мы тут смеемся над советом, а может были действительные основания предложить сериализацию.  
Дайте ссылку на трэд в котором Вам дали такой совет.

Answer (score 2):

Если вам что-то требуется искать в базе данных, никогда не храните эти данные в сериализованном/маршализованном виде. Даже в денормализованном (например, числа через запятую) виде эти данные хранить не стоит. SQL - специализированный и очень старый язык, созданный в условиях, когда компьютерное время стоило баснословных денег (по сравнению с временем программиста). На нем просто не удобно работать с денормализованными данными, вы теряете все преимущества SQL (скорость обработки, компактность записи), но встречаетесь со всеми его недостатками (сложность создания и отладки программ, скудные языковые средства).

Я не смогу дать вам полное решение, но приведу лишь две функции, которые работаю с сериализованными массивами PHP

```
-- Вспомогательная функция для проверки, входит ли в сериализованный массив запрашиваемый идентификатор
-- Возвращает 1 в случае если идентификатор входит в массив и 0 в противном случае
-- Аргументы:
--   `serialized` - строка. сериализованный PHP-массив
--   `category_id` - внешний ключ, для которого проверяется входит ли он в массив
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS is_id_in_serialized_array//
CREATE FUNCTION is_id_in_serialized_array(
  `serialized`  TEXT,
  `category_id` INT
)
RETURNS INT
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
  DECLARE `is_array`     TINYINT;
  DECLARE `count_array`  INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE `i`            INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE `inner_array`  TEXT;
  DECLARE `inner_offset` INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE `index`        TEXT;
  DECLARE `value`        TEXT;

  SET `is_array` := LOCATE('a:', `serialized`);
  IF `is_array` <= 0 THEN
    -- Это не массив
    RETURN NULL;
  ELSE
    -- Вычисляем количество элементов в массиве
    SET count_array := SUBSTRING(`serialized`, 3, LOCATE(':', `serialized`, 3) - 3);
    -- Извлекаем внутренее содержимое массива
    SET inner_array := SUBSTRING(`serialized`, LOCATE('{', `serialized`) + 1, LOCATE('}', `serialized`) - LOCATE('{', `serialized`));

    WHILE i < count_array DO
      SET `index` := SUBSTRING(inner_array, 3, LOCATE(';', inner_array, 3) - 3);
      SET inner_array := SUBSTRING(inner_array, LOCATE(';', inner_array, 3) + 1);
      SET `value` := SUBSTRING(inner_array, 3, LOCATE(';', inner_array, 3) - 3);
      SET inner_array := SUBSTRING(inner_array, LOCATE(';', inner_array, 3) + 1);
      SET i := i + 1;
      IF category_id = `value` THEN
        RETURN 1;
      END IF;
    END WHILE;

    RETURN 0;
  END IF;
END//
```

Еще одна

```
-- Функция извлекает из сериализованного PHP-массива значение заданной переменной.
-- Умеет обрабатывать переменные типа integer и string.
-- Аргументы:
--   `serialized` - строка. сериализованный PHP-массив
--   `var_name`   - строка. имя переменной, значение которой надо извлечь
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS get_var_from_serialized//
CREATE FUNCTION get_var_from_serialized(
  `serialized` TEXT        CHARSET utf8,
  `var_name`   VARCHAR(50) CHARSET utf8
)
RETURNS TEXT CHARSET utf8
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
  DECLARE `search_string` VARCHAR(255);
  DECLARE `search_string_length` TINYINT;
  DECLARE `var_position` MEDIUMINT;
  DECLARE `cur_position` MEDIUMINT;
  DECLARE `var_type` CHAR(1);
  DECLARE `result`   TEXT CHARSET utf8;
  DECLARE `result_length` MEDIUMINT;

  SET `search_string` = CONCAT('s:', CHAR_LENGTH(`var_name`), ':"', `var_name`, '"');
  SET `search_string_length` = CHAR_LENGTH(`search_string`);
  SET `var_position` = INSTR(`serialized`, `search_string`);

  -- проверяем, найдено ли имя запрошенной переменной
  IF NOT `var_position` THEN
    SET `result` = NULL;

  -- если найдено, определяем тип переменной и обрабатываем
  ELSE
    SET `var_type` = SUBSTRING(`serialized`, `var_position` + `search_string_length` + 1, 1);

    -- тип извлекаемой переменной - integer
    IF `var_type` = 'i' THEN
      SET `result` = CAST(SUBSTRING(`serialized`, `var_position` + `search_string_length` + 3, 10) AS signed);

    -- тип извлекаемой переменной - string
    ELSEIF `var_type` = 's' THEN
      -- извлекаем информацию, какой длинны значение переменной
      SET `result_length` = CAST(SUBSTRING(`serialized`, `var_position` + `search_string_length` + 3, 10) AS signed);
      -- т.к. в сериализованном PHP-массиве длинна измеряется в байтах, а не в количестве символов,
      -- а в MySQL функция SUBSTRING() измеряет текст в символах, приходится в цикле добавлять
      -- к результату по 1 символу и измерять его длинну в байтах, до достижения заданной длинны.
      SET `result` = '';
      SET `cur_position` = `var_position` + `search_string_length` + CHAR_LENGTH(`result_length`) + 5;
      WHILE LENGTH(`result`) < `result_length` DO
        SET `result` = CONCAT(`result`, SUBSTRING(`serialized`, `cur_position`, 1));
        SET `cur_position` = `cur_position` + 1;
      END WHILE;

    -- не поддерживаемый тип переменной
    ELSE
      SET `result` = NULL;

    END IF;

  END IF;

  RETURN `result`;
END//
```

Это сложно читать, это сложно сопровождать, это медленно работает. Данные живут гораздо дольше приложений. Пожалуйста, не используйте денормализованные строки в СУБД. Если в этом есть производственная необходимость, хотя бы используйте формат JSON. В PostgreSQL он уже давно поддерживается, в MySQL он вводится начиная с MySQL 5.7. Если вы будете использоватся для хранения в базах данных уникальные форматы языков, вроде сериализации, вы заложите в базу данных технологический долг и сделаете более трудоемкой и дорогой поддержку базы данных в будущем.